# How to speed up rgb plotting in real time in python

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib, animation

I've been asked to code a crazy idea.  We want to have a screen that will display every possible image it can produce using RGB format and every pixel available.  Of course, we understand that such code would take millions of years to run its course (even more), but still, this is what we want to do.  I have something that works pretty well, the only problem is that the plotting of the image is really slow...

I am currently using matplotlib,  I am open to try something else for speed's sake, but I must admit that I am not familiar with other tools and I often find the documentation hard to follow (with glumpy for exemple)

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import itertools
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets 
plt.ion()
import ctypes

# Getting the screensize
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
screensize = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)


fig = plt.figure()

#To remove toolbar from figure
try:
     win = fig.canvas.manager.window
except AttributeError:
     win = fig.canvas.window()          
toolbar = win.findChild(QtWidgets.QToolBar) #same
toolbar.setVisible(False)                   #same
fig.canvas.manager.full_screen_toggle()     #To display the result in fullscreen

# To remove white space between axis and figure
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1]) #position: left, bottom, width, height
ax.set_axis_off()
pixel_x, pixel_y = screensize[::-1]

initial_image = np.zeros((pixel_x,pixel_y,3)).astype(np.uint8)
image = ax.imshow(initial_image, animated = True)
ch = ax.get_children()
fig.canvas.draw()

# itertools allow me to iterate over all possible image pretty efficiently
for x in itertools.product(np.arange(0,256,steps,dtype = "uint8"),repeat = pixel_y*pixel_x*3):

    x = np.fromiter(x,dtype = np.uint8) # I read that np.fromiter is quicker than np.array
    x = x.reshape(pixel_x,pixel_y,3)    # Putting everything back in an image appropriate 
                                        # format
   
    ch[-2].set_data(x)       # I try not to redraw the entire figure by only changing this
    ax.draw_artist(ch[-2])   # I redraw the artist
    fig.canvas.blit(fig.bbox)# Read online that this was quicker
    fig.canvas.flush_events()# same...



    j+=1
    if j % 10 == 0:
        print(f'{j/(time.time() - t):.2f} iterations per seconde')
```

So I found that the iterations over the `itertools.product` relatively fast : this part can go as fast as 40-45 iterations per seconds. Converting itertools output in an numpy array using `np.fromiter` slows down the process a bunch : it falls to approximately 25 iterations per second.  Reshaping the result in a image appropriate format does not seem to slow down anything.  Finally, when I include all of the plotting with `set_data` method and everything, it slows down to 5-6 interations per second which is really slow...

If you have any insight on how I could make this process more efficient, please let me know!  It will be really appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried looking into OpenCV? It uses numpy arrays to represent images so it could be pretty fast

Comment: Have you thought about how silly this is?  At 60fps, it would take 3 days to run through all the possible colors for ONE PIXEL.  What's the point?

Comment: I did, but from what I understand, OpenCV is more for image processing than anything else. In every example I found, they actually use matplotlib to display the result.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, I know it is silly in this context.  But I might very well want to do something very similar in the near future (display RGB image in real time at high fps), and I feel that it should be doable to achieve a better result.

Comment: This is insane! Assuming steps is optimistically equal to 128 and the screen is only 400x300 (small), the number of iteration will be about 10**83177. This is bigger than the number of atoms in the observable universe! The number is actually so big that it cannot even be printed in this comment. Assuming you can use a machine a billion billion billion billion times faster than all supercomputers in the world used together, just iterating over all possible solution would take far far more time than the age of the universe... What is the point of doing such a thing apart from wasting energy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use matplotlib with caution
2. If somebody uses matplotlib for imaging, stop reading
3. For showing video, use openCV. For showing image use opencv/Pillow unless you dont want to show anything extra alongside the image like axes
4. Take more time thinking about what you are doing, because what you are doing is really not worth doing.

OPENCV implementation (333-500 FPS)

```
import numpy as np
import time
import itertools

import cv2


steps = 1
pixel_x, pixel_y = [3, 3]
initial_image = np.zeros((pixel_x, pixel_y, 3)).astype(np.uint8)

import time

for x in itertools.product(
    np.arange(0, 256, steps, dtype="uint8"), repeat=pixel_y * pixel_x * 3
):
    s = time.time()
    x = np.fromiter(x, dtype=np.uint8)
    x = x.reshape(pixel_x, pixel_y, 3)
    cv2.imshow("Frame", x)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):

        break
    print("FPS: ", 1 / (time.time() - s))
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: _If somebody uses matplotlib for imaging, stop reading_ -- This is excellent advice.  Matplotlib does a lot of things well, but it also does a lot of things poorly that are done well in other packages.

Comment: @Martin Thank you!  I know it's not worth doing.  I've been asked to code that for an artistic installation, where they want to show how such crazy number can actually be represented by a simple code.  I was mainly curious on how to display RGB image efficiently.

Comment: @Pierrot-Baptiste That make sense. Then, If I may advice you... You dont really need to go over ~60FPS as its eyes' limit. Anything above this FPS will not make any difference(moreover capping at fixed lower FPS will make FPS stable). So instead of increasing performance, I suggest reducing color range and maybe inventing better visual algorithm for your purpose. This one is hell boring as it looks like one pixel is just blinking forever

Comment: @Martin If you've ever used a 144hz display vs. a 60hz display, there is a very visible difference.

Comment: @AKX For totally different reasons. 1) check out Eyes FPS, 2) You can make experiment yourself -> create blinking led and keep decreasing period, you will see smoothing effect around 40FPS where led stops 'blinking'. 3) Alternating current has 50HZ, yet you dont see home & street lights blinking... 4) Movies are even bellow 60FPS and are around 25 FPS... works just fine...

Comment: @Martin (1) A bit of googling says there's no such thing as a single "eyes FPS". (2) I'd imagine the blinking ("two separate images") starts to be perceived as motion, yes. But a smooth presentation is presumably what we'd be looking for. (3) Yes, because the light source doesn't immediately turn dark.

Comment: @AKX Strange, bit of googling revelead its around 60 FPS. Anyway, I dont want to go in circles... Just run some animation and keep incresing FPS, and you will see where you will get., thats the scientific method....

Comment: @Martin Yes absolutely, I will implement some changes to spice things up a little bit, as it is not much to look at right now :P  Thank you again for your input!